# 'c interfaces and implementations' (David Hanson) code install

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ubuntu-11.04

I'm trying to install the code that goes with the book: https://sites.google.com/site/cinterfacesimplementations/

Following the instructions given by the author here: http://cii.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/install.html

My computer has ubuntu 11.04 on 32 bit i686 architecture. Follow the authors instructions for 32 bit linux I try:

```
make CC='cc -DMAXALIGN=4' AS='cc -c -x assembler-with-cpp -traditional'
```

Where cc is gcc version 4.5.2
Which gives the following warnings and errors:

```
makefile:138: warning: overriding commands for target `maxalign'
makefile:135: warning: ignoring old    cc -DMAXALIGN=4 -g -Iinclude -c -o ap.o src/ap.c

In file included from src/thread.c:100:0:
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/asm/sigcontext.h:56:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct _fpreg’
/usr/include/bits/sigcontext.h:28:8: note: originally defined here
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/asm/sigcontext.h:61:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct _fpxreg’
/usr/include/bits/sigcontext.h:34:8: note: originally defined here
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/asm/sigcontext.h:67:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct _xmmreg’
/usr/include/bits/sigcontext.h:41:8: note: originally defined here
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/asm/sigcontext.h:71:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct _fpstate’
/usr/include/bits/sigcontext.h:50:8: note: originally defined here
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/asm/sigcontext.h:104:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct sigcontext’
/usr/include/bits/sigcontext.h:81:8: note: originally defined here
src/thread.c: In function ‘interrupt’:
src/thread.c:108:2: warning: ‘sigsetmask’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/signal.h:199)
make: *** [thread.o] Error 1
```

Not sure what to do here. 
Also puzzling is the /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu. Since if I do

```
uname -m
```

It prints i686 not i363.
Any ideas anyone?

Cheers,
Jim

Comment: What file(s) does "thread.c" include? Yes, i386 is correct - the differentiation in archiecture when building linux kernel is i386 or x86-64 (or powerpc, arm, mips, etc). "uname -m" shows the flavour that the kernel was built for - which is something along the lines of "generic pentium pro generation". [In the latest i386 kernel, you can't actually choose i386 as an architecture any longer, as the 1990-ish processor is no longer supported]

Answer (score 3):

On line 100 in thread.c — remove the `#include <asm/sigcontext.h>` (or comment it out). That should remove the "duplicate declaration". It won't fix use of deprecated interfaces (a problem with books written a decade ago and with code updated 5 years back), and if you try to run this on 64-bit processors, other problems occur that I haven't tried fixing.